# ¿A qué se debe el error "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by..."?

Tags: php, html, mysql, netbeans

```
<?php
include('./lib/dbcon.php'); 
dbcon(); 
include('session.php');
$get_id = $_GET['id'];

    $query = mysql_query("select * from stdevice 
        LEFT JOIN device_name ON stdevice.dev_id=device_name.dev_id
        where id = '$get_id'")or die(mysql_error());
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
?>
<div class="hide">                                  
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">

    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Equipo</label>
        <div class="controls">          
            <select id="qtype" name="dev_id" readonly="readonly" required>

            <option value="<?php echo $row['dev_id']; ?>" ><?php echo $row['dev_name']; ?></option>
                <?php
                $device_query = mysql_query("select * from device_name")or die(mysql_error());
                while($query_device_row = mysql_fetch_array($device_query)){
                $dev_name = $row['dev_name'];
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $query_device_row['dev_id']; ?>"><?php echo $query_device_row['dev_name'];  ?></option>
                <?php } ?>

                </select>
            </div>
      </div>
<div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Dispositivo Serial</label>
        <div class="controls">          
            <select id="qtype" name="dev_serial" readonly="readonly" required>

            <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" ><?php echo $row['dev_serial']; ?></option>
                <?php
                $device_query = mysql_query("select * from stdevice")or die(mysql_error());
                while($query_device_row = mysql_fetch_array($device_query)){
                $dev_serial = $row['dev_serial'];
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $query_device_row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $query_device_row['dev_serial'];  ?></option>
                <?php } ?>

                </select>
            </div>
      </div>      
</form>
</div>
<?php 
mysql_query("update stdevice set dev_status='Dump' where id = '$get_id'")or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("insert into activity_log (date,username,action) values(NOW(),'$admin_username','Dump Device $dev_name CÓDIGO:$dev_serial')")or die(mysql_error());                     
header('location:damage.php');
?>
```

En este código me sale lo siguiente:

> ```
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by 
> (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\isc\admin\dump.php:26) in 
> C:\xampp\htdocs\isc\admin\dump.php on line 54
> ```

Que debo hacer para componerlo

Comment: Estas enviando el cuerpo antes que las cabeceras por lo que por eso te da el error. El header debe ser lo primero en enviar.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta? O_O

Comment: Creo que el título de la pregunta es totalmente desacertado.

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta es un duplicado de un duplicado

Answer (score 2):

Fijate al final de tu código, tienes un header.

---

Las funciones PHP que envían o modifican las cabeceras HTTP se deben ejecutar antes de que se haya empezado a enviar la página solicitada al usuario. Si no, se producirá el siguiente error:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent
>   (output started at file:line)

Las funciones PHP que modifican las cabeceras HTTP son las siguientes:

> 1. header() / header_remove()
> 2. session_start() / session_regenerate_id()
> 3. setcookie() / setrawcookie()

*Mas información:* http://librosweb.es/foro/pregunta/128/como-solucionar-el-problema-headers-already-sent-de-php/

Answer (score 0):

No se si estoy en lo correcto pero ese error también lo genera cuando una linea antes del header tiene error, generalmente en las querys que estas haciendo, pudiera tener un error, la ejecución no puede seguir y manda error diciéndote que no que no se puede redireccionar.

En su momento yo llegue a usar esto para solucionar algo parecido:

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
// al final del documento:
<?php
ob_end_flush();
?>
```